# SSH Local Script on Remote Permission Denied/Path Not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, permissions

I'm Running a master.sh file from machine A to B via SSH.

This master file call another 4 snippet .sh  that has to be executed using other user.

i run the master.sh i'm currently on **/pathA/pathB/master.sh**

```
ssh machineB "bash -sh"  < master.sh
```

master.sh call other script always located on **/pathA/pathB/**

```
system_metrics=$(su mdm -c ./snippet1.sh)
```

**result : bash: ./snippet1.sh: Permission denied**
**Using full path**

```
 system_metrics=$(su mdm -c /pathA/pathB/snippet1.sh)
```

**result : bash: no such file or directory**

```
source ./listen_port.sh 
check_port_mdm
```

**result for that code** No such file or directory

Other info :

**result from ls -l on script snippet1** -rwxrwxrwx 1 mdm mdm 12152

**result from ls -l on /usr/bin/ssh:** -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 690952

What can I do?

Comment: what is the Permission of snippet1.sh file and 2nd issue give the full path rather than relative path.

Comment: 1- Edited Question Other info

2- Edited Question with result of full path

Comment: You are checking the existence of files and their permissions on the remote server right? The script will be executed on the remote server and so will be referencing other files on the remote server.

Comment: Local Server has all of these files while the Remote Server does not.

Comment: can you ssh to the machine and execute the script manually? this command `su mdm -c /pathA/pathB/snippet1.sh`

Comment: what you are trying is to execute the local server shell script in remote server after ssh into the remote machine?

Comment: @skr  If i run manually after ssh it just run on the machine A (Locale). If i run 
ssh machineB "bash -sh"  < snippet1.sh works on machine B.

and Yes i'm trying to execute local server shell script in remote

Comment: what else could I try?

Comment: Clearly, all the scripts that master.sh calls have to exist on the remote machine too.

Comment: but master.sh also is not on the remote. Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in order to close the questions **Running a sh file local script from Machine A to Remote Machine B:**

- Running an sh (Not available on the machine B) file that **does not call any other snippet.sh**, can be done using ssh.
- Running an sh master (Not available on the machine B) file **that calls other snippet.sh**, cannot be done using ssh 
  if the snippet.sh is not available on the Machine B.